# device-mapper: remove ioctl on luks-xxxx failed: Device or resource busy

Tags: 13.10, luks, umount

While I was away from my computer, my encrypted USB drive got accidentally unmounted somehow  (although it was still physically connected at the time).  I haven't been able to recover (haven't tried a reboot yet).  I have now completely disconnected the device, but I still get "Device or resource busy" when I try to remove the dangling entry in /dev/mapper.  Can I reconnect and mount the drive without a reboot?

Here's what I have tried (long name changed to "xxxxx")...

```
$ sudo dmsetup ls
luks-xxxxx (252:1)
luks-yyyyy (252:0)

$ sudo umount /dev/mapper/luks-xxxxx
umount: /dev/mapper/luks-xxxxx: not mounted

$ sudo fuser --kill /dev/mapper/luks-xxxxx
$ echo $?
1

$ sudo dmsetup info -c luks-xxxxx
Name       Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID
luks-xxxxx 252   1 L--w    1    1      0 CRYPT-LUKS1-xxxxx-luks-xxxxx

$ sudo dmsetup remove luks-xxxxx
device-mapper: remove ioctl on luks-xxxx failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed
```

After reconnecting the device...

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen "/dev/sde1" "luks-xxxxx"
Device luks-xxxxx already exists.
```

[EDIT] I solved the problem, this time, by closing a GUI text editor which had no open files, but had been launched from a folder on the device in question.  So the question becomes more specific: **How can you identify which application is holding the device open?**

Bear in mind that `lsof` doesn't seem to present an easy solution because, once the device is disconnected, the associated names provided by `lsof` no longer include the name of the disconnected device.

Comment: Running into the same problem but on CentOS. Found this link: http://www.krenel.org/unable-to-remove-lvm-volumen-created-by-xen-device-or-resource-busy/   but I don't show the device mounted

Comment: Seems remarkably similar to this *closed-as-fixed* bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=574126

Comment: Word of warning: Mounting with sudo, as shown here, may prevent you from ejecting normally using the user-space file-manager.

Comment: This hasn't happened to me much lately, but today it did (I accidentally unplugged a drive).  On Ubuntu 18.04, the error is "Failed to activate device File exists", but it doesn't give much help regarding what file (or what luks-xxxx name).  Fortunately, I was able to identify that by looking at `/dev/disk/by-uuid` with and without the drive connected.  The solution was the same as before (`sudo dmsetup ls` followed by `sudo lsof |grep xxx,x` followed by closing/killing processes).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After two years of fighting with this, I think I've finally cracked it completely!

`dmsetup ls` gives you the data you need:

```
$ sudo dmsetup ls
luks-xxxxx (252:1)
```

then

```
sudo lsof |grep 252,1   ## notice translation: (252:1) => 252,1
```

*It seems that `sudo` may be critical here -- at least in some cases.*

---

This should give you the information necessary to close all open files on the device -- including names of open files and process IDs for the offending applications.  You may be able to simply go to those apps and close them, but a brute force approach might be something like:

```
kill -9 (process ID)
```

Once you've closed all the files, some of the command-line tools shown in the question may be necessary in order to close down the existing mount before it can be reopened normally.

Comment: Notice the slight translation required: `(252:1)` becomes `252,1`.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for this response that finally works!

Comment: hm. weirdly enough, lsof doesn't show any processes holding handles on the (stale) device.

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo lsof |grep 253:3` didn't work for me lsof. There was no output on stdout, and on stderr 100s of errors like `no pwd entry for UID 70`

Comment: @TylerRick, Notice the slight translation required: `(253:3)` becomes `grep 253,3`. I don't know about your stderr issues but this translation is probably necessary to get results on stdout.

Comment: This is pretty good. It doesn't work in every case though (eg. when SCST has open files). After all these decades you would think someone would create a tool that can show absolutely every open device or file. Ugh.

Answer (score 15):

Try to stop LVM group prior to stop cypher:

`lvchange -a n [LVM_Group_name]`

then

`cryptsetup -v luksClose [LUKS_name]`

Sample:

```
lvchange -a n My_vg_crypt
cryptsetup -v luksClose My_Crypt
```

Comment: Use [@nobar's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/682007/478705) first (but try `kill` before `kill -9`).

However @nobar's solution wasn't sufficient for me - it seems that the kernel itself had the device open because of the LVM device mappings - which this answer resolved.

Comment: +1 In my case the accepted answer's `grep` didn't find any matches, but this worked.

Answer (score 4):

next time try a lazy umount

```
umount -l /<folder>
```

This works for me most of the times, especially useful with hung-up NFS-drives.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't help for the problem at hand.  I'm assuming that you can't actually use LUKS over NFS, and that this was just a shot-in-the-dark suggestion.

Comment: this was exactly my problem, i forgot that i need to unmount mapped storage first :D

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I manage to solve this problem on Linux Mint 17.3 (~Ubuntu Trusty):

1. remove the device from device-mapper

   ```
   $ sudo dmsetup remove luks-xxyyzz
   ```
2. map it back

   ```
   $ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdc1 luks-xxyyzz
   Enter passphrase for /dev/sdc1:
   ```

Now the devices is accessible.

Comment: This post might be helpful to someone, but as noted in the question -- sometimes `dmsetup remove` reports "Command failed".

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation but could not solve the problem by removing the `luks-xxxx` device. Instead I had to remove `ubuntu--vg-root`.

My situation was:

- I accidentally removed the device before it was locked.
- Trying to lock or remove the luks device after the fact failed with a *busy* error message.
- Unlocking the same device failed because a device with the same name already existed.
- `lsof` did not show any open handles for the device.

What did help was to unplug the physical device and remove the `ubuntu--vg-root` device with the following command:

```
sudo dmsetup remove ubuntu--vg-root
```

At that point I was able to normally activate and decrypt the external device again with my usual setup:

```
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda3
sudo lvchange --activate y ubuntu-vg/root
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with an internal disk. After `vgscan` did not return any results despite the fact that the volume groups were there and accessible, this was the last resort that finally solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have a flaky USB drive that is part of a btrfs raid 1 setup and this was what worked. I have no idea why `cryptsetup close` wouldn't close but `dmsetup remove` worked!

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally powered off an encrypted USB drive in operation, and ended up with this problem.
I researched this a lot -- reading many questions asked on many forums.
After trying a bunch of other proposed solutions (and goofing one up that might've worked) and noting that for a lot of people it seemed to magically fix itself at some point in time, I tried the obvious easy fix:

*Reboot*

Magic! The computer forgot all of its woes, and happily mounted the drive.

Comment: If you don't mind rebooting, then of course! I asked the question only because I was trying to avoid being forced into a reboot by a recurring issue.

Comment: Oh! And there it is, right there in your question, plainly saying "without a reboot." Sorry. Of all the questions I looked at, this one seemed to have some of the most helpful info (and was still open in my browser) so that's where I decided to leave my comment to "complete" the info. I apparently didn't go back and re-read the question so I could at least acknowledge that my "answer" didn't answer it. Sorry, and thanks for pointing that out; I'll be more careful.